# If the speed of light is a constant value and the wavelength is constant (antenna), how can one antenna transit/receive different frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, wavelength, antennas, radio

The speed of light is about 300,000,000 m/s, and the wavelength is determined by the design of the antenna, how can one antenna transmit different frequencies other than just the one defined by

f = c / wavelength

If the frequency needs to be changed, shouldn't the wavelength require changing too, but this doesn't happen, the antenna remains the same length?

Comment: "...but this doesn't happen, the antenna remains the same length?" <-- Is this a question or a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a simple antenna determines the **optimum** wavelength of operation, but it may still function adequately well at other wavelengths. This is especially true for radio reception at wavelengths more than a few meters, where natural noise is so high that an efficient antenna isn't necessary.

There are not-so-simple antenna designs that operate optimally over a range of wavelengths. One example is the [log periodic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-periodic_antenna).

Comment: So a non optimum antenna performs inefficiently, how does that appear? Does it consume more power for the same signal strength as the optimal antenna would make consuming less power?

Comment: @epicMan123 A suboptimal transmitting antenna will radiate less power than an optimal antenna on transmission and deliver less power than an optimal antenna on reception. The principle size-related effect is that it reflects power back to the transmitter or, on reception, fails to extract the optimum power from the passing wave.